# Why angular.bootstrap code not working with versions before AngularJS V1.6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

My problem is that when i include the URL:http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js
in the below `<script>` tag code works perfectly fine,
instead if i use this URL: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js, angular is not loaded/bootstrapped Why?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Program6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="sampledata" />
        <p>{{ sampledata }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS code in case it helps to resolve the problem:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: URL:http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js is from the example code on angular bootstrapping from the AngularJS official website.

Comment: `snapshot` is the latest beta build (v1.6.5-build.5390+sha.a86a319). It is better to use the latest stable release: https://unpkg.com/angular@1.6.4/angular.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AngularJS 1.6+ Use:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

For Older versions of AngularJS Use:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

From the Docs:

> - [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) *(deprecated, use `angular.element(callback)` instead of `angular.element(document).ready(callback)`)*
>
> [— AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

For more information see,

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)
- [AngularJS feat(jqLite): implement jqLite(f) as alias to jqLite(document).ready(f)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/369fb7f4f73664bcdab0350701552d8bef6f605e)